# Given final block not properly padded DES

Tags: java, encryption, des

I have used DES encryption to encrypt/decrypt a data. This code was working fine. But now this code is failing on Linux box with padding error, on Windows box I am not seeing this issue. 
These are my observations

- The older encryption key are working fine. The newer ones generated is causing the problem
- Runs on Windows machine not on Linux machine

Can anyone let me know what might be causing this issue?

Here is my code

```
 /**
 * Generate the private key using the passed string.
 * 
 * @param keyGeneratorString
 *            : The string which is to be used to generate the private key.
 * @return : SecretKey else null.
 */
public SecretKey getKey(String keyGeneratorString) {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
    DESKeySpec keySpec = null;
    try {
        // only the first 8 Bytes of the constructor argument are used
        // as material for generating the keySpec
        keySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyGeneratorString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        // Get the DES encryption standard instance
        keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        // Generate and return the key.
        return keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        logger.error("****** Error while generating key : "
                + uee.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
        logger.error("****** Error while generating key : "
                + ike.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while generating key : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while generating key : "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    // There was error while generating the key hence return null.
    return null;
}

/**
 * Encrypt the string using the SecretKey.
 * 
 * @param stringToBeEncrypted
 *            : The String to be encrypted.
 * @param key
 *            : The secret key to be used for encryption.
 * @return : Encrypted byte[] or null.
 */
public byte[] encrypt(String stringToBeEncrypted, SecretKey key) {
    Cipher cipherInst;
    try {
        cipherInst = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipherInst.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);// cipher is not thread
                                                    // safe
        byte[] encrypted = cipherInst.doFinal(stringToBeEncrypted
                .getBytes());
        return encrypted;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while encrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while encrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while encrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while encrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while encrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Decrypt the string using the SecretKey.
 * 
 * @param stringToBeDecrypted : byte[] to be decrypted.
 * @param key : The secret key to be used for decryption.
 * @return : Decrypted byte[] or null.
 */
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] stringToBeDecrypted, SecretKey key) {
    Cipher cipherInst;
    try {
        cipherInst = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipherInst.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] original = cipherInst
                .doFinal(stringToBeDecrypted);
        return original;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while decrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while decrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while decrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while decrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        logger.error("****** Error while decrypting : "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine (aside from using DES, using ECB and not authenticating ciphertexts). How are you transmitting the bytes between sender and receiver? You seem to be having problems with the "new keys". Can you give an example of such a new key?

Comment: Examine the decrypted last block to determine the padding, there are only a couple of padding methods and only one that should really be used: PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5, the same algorithm). Add examples go the last block from the "good" and "bad" decryption.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when converting Strings to bytes that you always use the same encoding.  This line

```
byte[] encrypted = cipherInst.doFinal(stringToBeEncrypted
            .getBytes());
```

uses the default character encoding for your machine which may well be different between Linux and Windows.  Use a consistent encoding like "UTF8" as you do for generating the `keySpec`.

```
byte[] encrypted = cipherInst.doFinal(stringToBeEncrypted
            .getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Note that a "padding error" is usually no such thing; it's a very misleading error message.

Comment: Changing the encryption input encoding (or rather using a fixed one) shouldn't change anything on the decryption error. This is something else.